# How to get the date in java by setting DAY_OF_WEEK AND WEEK_OF_MONTH to calender class

Tags: java

i want to get the date after modifying the day of the week using Calender class in java

**i want to print 16 7 2015(DD/MM/YYYY);**

```
int monthIndex=6,weekIndex=2,dayIndex=4;



            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();    
            c.set(Calendar.MONTH, (monthIndex + 1));
            c.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, weekIndex+1 );
            c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayIndex+1);

            int recurMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int recWeek=c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
            int recurDate = c.get(Calendar.DATE);
            int recurYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);           
            int dayofMonth=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            int dayofWeek=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
            int dayofweekinmonth=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH);
```

**but its showing wrong date**

Comment: WELL, NOT BY YELLING...

Comment: What are you asking? Your question isn't clear. In addition remove the uppercase in the title please

Comment: Which Java version are you using?

Comment: Is the wrong date **8/7/2015** ?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format date using SimpleDateFormat:

```
public void printDate(int weekOfMonth, int dayOFWeek) {

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);

    calendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, weekOfMonth);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayOFWeek);

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    System.out.println(df.format(calendar.getTime()));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Its pretty clear, I guess.

```
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    today.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
    today.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, 5);
    System.out.println(today.get(Calendar.DATE));
```

The code is self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

To move to the following Monday:

```
LocalDate.of( 1986 , 2 , 23 )                            // Represent a certain date, without time-of-day and without time zone.
    .with( TemporalAdjusters.next( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) )  // Move to the following Monday.
    .format(                                             // Generate a string representing this object’s value, using an automatically localizing formatter.
        DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale( Locale.UK )
    )
```

…or, for "third Monday in the same month":

```
LocalDate.of( 1986 , 2 , 23 )                            // Represent a certain date, without time-of-day and without time zone.
    .with( TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth( 3 , DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) )  // Move to the third Monday of the same month.
    .format(                                             // Generate a string representing this object’s value, using an automatically localizing formatter.
        DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale( Locale.UK )
    )
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that supplanted the troublesome old legacy date-time classes.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may change at any moment, so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the JVM’s current default is applied implicitly. Better to be explicit, as the default may be changed at any moment *during runtime* by any code in any thread of any app within the JVM.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Or specify a date. You may set the month by a number, with sane numbering 1-12 for January-December.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , 2 , 23 ) ;  // Years use sane direct numbering (1986 means year 1986). Months use sane numbering, 1-12 for January-December.
```

Or, better, use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum objects pre-defined, one for each month of the year. Tip: Use these `Month` objects throughout your codebase rather than a mere integer number to make your code more self-documenting, ensure valid values, and provide [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , Month.FEBRUARY , 23 ) ;
```

## Adjusters

To move to another date, use a `TemporalAdjuster` implementation found in the [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) class. Specify the desired day-of-week using a `DayOfWeek` enum object.

```
LocalDate nextMonday = ld.with( TemporalAdjusters.next( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) ) ;
```

If your goal is something like "move to the third Monday of the month", use another `TemporalAdjuster` implementation.

```
TemporalAdjuster ta = TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth( 3 , DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) ;
LocalDate thirdMondayOfSameMonth = ld.with( ta ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

With a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) complying with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings or java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).